# вставить запись в базу или обновить существующую строку

Tags: php, mysql

Прошу помощи, делаю импорт из csv в mysql.
Написал импорт, но столкнулся с тем что будут обновлятся 3 таблицы постоянно и не знаю как правильно написать условие проверки на сущ. запись и обновление информации в ней и добавление новой.

```
 $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO testtabl (id, col_1, col_2, col_3) 
VALUES (NULL, '$mass[0]', '$mass[1]', '$mass[2]') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col_1=col_1");
```

Сразу заметил, что данные при каждом запуске скрипта добавляются в таблицу, когда указал для col_1 что уникальный index тогда при запуске если существует такая запись ничего не обновляется, если нет добавляется.

Собственно вопрос если в строке в одном из столбцов обновились данные, допустим в col_3 при запуске они у меня не обновляются, подскажите что не учёл или где ошибка.

Comment: *делаю импорт из csv в mysql* Загружайте данные во временную таблицу (`LOAD DATA INFILE`), а потом оттуда запросами раскладывайте по рабочим таблицам. Читать в PHP, парсить в массив, а потом пихать в БД по одной записи - несерьёзно...

Comment: > условие проверки на сущ. запись и обновление информации в ней. Определите единственный критерий, который будет отличать - существующая это запись, или нет. Из этих столбцов сделайте составной первичный ключ или составной уникальный индекс. Если не можете этого сделать, добавьте в свою таблицу столбец типа "ID".

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем за советы.
Решил всё по другому.

```
     $mysqli->query("REPLACE INTO testtabl (id, col_1, col_2, col_3) 
    VALUES (NULL, '$mass[0]', '$mass[1]', '$mass[2]')");
```